# Reputation different on the same page (Question page)?

Tags: bug, status-declined, live-refresh, question-lists

I mean, I know rep changes because of caching. I also know the rep in the top bar is more "dynamic" than most other parts of the site, but reputation differing on the **same section of the same page**[image: Repissue]?

Comment: I see your point, but this is really too minor and would require too many changes for such a small problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you load new questions by clicking the banner? That will load new questions with the *current* values for their reputation, while any occurrences of their name *already* in the list will show the values that they were when you originally loaded the page. Both values show the same for me.

> [image]

I'm not aware of any other way that this could happen.

Comment: Yeah I loaded them by clicking the banner, maybe I refreshed mid-upvote?

Comment: Well, loading via that banner doesn't update the values the *moment* you load them. When a new item gets pushed for you to load, all the information for it is already cached. So if two items get pushed, the reputation, votes, etc for that post are pushed with it. So if more posts come later, they get added on, but the reputation, votes, etc may not be the same as previously pushed items.

Comment: Very clever! How on earth did you know that?

Comment: I've seen this happen on Meta countless times when I go away for long periods of time, load new questions, then refresh the page to see they already have several votes and answers. If you're not loading them as soon as they come in, the information you're seeing is probably inaccurate.